# Firebase grecaptcha is undefined with react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I copied the code from this bit here in the documentation:

```
window.recaptchaVerifier.render().then(function(widgetId) {
  grecaptcha.reset(widgetId);
}
```

However in my react project `grecaptcha` is undefined. I don't see where they declare it as a variable or where to get it from in firebase.

Comment: When you render recaptchaVerifier, it automatically loads the grecaptcha dependency if it is not already loaded.

Comment: should I try calling window.grecaptcha?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure why but this worked for me just fine:

```
window.recaptchaVerifier.render().then(widgetId => {
  window.recaptchaVerifier.reset(widgetId);
});
```

Instead of doing `grecaptcha`, I just did the `window.recaptchaVerifier` and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Just want to add that the resetting does not work if you have `appVerificationDisabledForTesting = true`.  In that case, the only thing that works for me is to recreate `window.recaptchaVerifier`