# Firebase recaptcha container empty with no error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am trying to deploy the Firebase reCaptcha container into my react app, however after following the instructions in the documentation, no reCaptcha is display and no error is thrown. The code I have implemented is the following:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";

declare global {
  interface Window { recaptchaVerifier: any; }
}

const PhoneVerification = () => {
  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "...",
    databaseURL: "...",
    projectId: "...",
    storageBucket: "...",
    messagingSenderId: "...",
    appId: "..."
  };
  useEffect(()=> {
    if (!firebase.apps.length) firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container', {
      'size': 'normal',
      'callback': function(response: any) {
        // reCAPTCHA solved, allow signInWithPhoneNumber.
        // ...
        console.log('callback executed');
        console.log(response);
      },
      'expired-callback': function() {
        // Response expired. Ask user to solve reCAPTCHA again.
        // ...
        console.log('expired');
      }
    });
  })

  return (
    <div id="main">
      main
      <div id="recaptcha-container">

      </div>
    </div>

)};

export default PhoneVerification;
```

Is there something missing in order for the reCaptcha to render?

Given that no error is thrown I am quite lost on how to fix this problem, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I needed to reset the recaptchaVerifier as shown [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48789732/firebase-grecaptcha-is-undefined-with-react)

The final code for it to work is as follows:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";

declare global {
  interface Window { recaptchaVerifier: any; }
}

const PhoneVerification = () => {
  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "...",
    databaseURL: "...",
    projectId: "...",
    storageBucket: "...",
    messagingSenderId: "...",
    appId: "..."
  };
  useEffect(()=> {

    if (!firebase.apps.length) firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container', {
      'size': 'normal',
      'callback': function(response: any) {
        // reCAPTCHA solved, allow signInWithPhoneNumber.
        // ...
        console.log('callback executed');
        console.log(response);
      },
      'expired-callback': function() {
        // Response expired. Ask user to solve reCAPTCHA again.
        // ...
        console.log('expired');
      }
    });
    window.recaptchaVerifier.render().then((widgetId: any) => {
      window.recaptchaVerifier.reset(widgetId);
    });
  })

  return (
    <div id="main">
      main
      <div id="recaptcha-container">

      </div>
    </div>

)};

export default PhoneVerification;
```